# How can I get can i get an existing HazelcastInstance?

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_using_an_existing_hazelcast_cluster says "You can pass an existing HazelcastInstance in the cluster manager to reuse an existing cluster".
If there is a Hazelcast Cluster already running, how can I get that in my code?

Answer (score 3):

You can get all Hazelcast instances running in the JVM by using the `getAllHazelcastInstances` method:

```java
Set<HazelcastInstance> hzSet = 
  com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances();
```

or you can configure the instance name in Hazelcast member configuration and then retrieve it by given name:

```java
HazelcastInstance hz =
  com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName(String);
```

For other possibilities check JavaDoc of the `Hazelcast` class:

- https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Hazelcast.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my problem is if the Hazelcast is running explecitely in different JVM and from my code i want to get HazelcastInstance. How that would be possible?